# Python Tkinter doesn't show the label when I press the button

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have one Input and one button. I want the value of the input (Entry) to when I press the button. When I type `print(mtext)` it works well, but when I put it in a Label it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Mohamed Atef")
root.geometry("900x600")

var = StringVar()
var.set("Please write something")
label = Label(root, textvariable=var, padx=10, pady=10)

#input
text = StringVar()
entry = Entry(root, textvariable=text)

def mohamed():
       mtext = text.get()
       mohamed = Label(root, textvariable=mtext)
       mohamed.pack()

#button
buttonText = StringVar()
buttonText.set("Click me !")
button = Button(root, textvariable=buttonText, command=mohamed)

label.pack()
entry.pack()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as Flilp, your finished product would look like this

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Mohamed Atef")
root.geometry("900x600")

var = StringVar()
var.set("Please write something")
label = Label(root, textvariable=var, padx=10, pady=10)

#input
text = StringVar()
entry = Entry(root, textvariable=text)

def mohamed() :
       mtext = text.get()
       mohamed = Label(root, text=mtext)
       mohamed.pack()

#button
buttonText = StringVar()
buttonText.set("Click me !")
button = Button(root, textvariable=buttonText, command=mohamed)

label.pack()
entry.pack()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks it works good the problem was i should change textvariable to text in the label which i'd like to show Exactly like you wrote Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want text that's in your `Entry` to appear under your labels you could do:

```
def mohamed():
    mohamed = Label(root, textvariable=text)
    mohamed.pack()
```

Your code didn't work because value passed as textvariable should be tkinter `StringVar()` not `string`.

If you don't want the text to be constantly updated when you change your `Entry` you should do:

```
def mohamed():
    mtext = text.get()
    mohamed = Label(root, text=mtext)
    mohamed.pack()
```